# SharePoint 2013 - Multiple custom login pages

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, custom-login-page

If you are using multiple authentication methods, and need to modify multiple login pages (one for each auth type) is there a way to do this without backing up and modifying the default files on the file system?

I have an environment where the users first get to the _login page where they select an authentication provider.  This page has a url of the form: sharepoint.mydomain.com/_login/default.aspx

This page is located on the file system at C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN

On this page the user selects either 'Windows Authentication' or "Forms Authentication"

For "Windows Authentication" a login form pops up.  Great.

For "Forms Authentication" the user is taken to another page with a url of the form: sharepoint.mydomain.com/_forms/default.aspx

However, I have learned that editing the file in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\FORMS does *not* impact the render of this page.

Some other research revealed that editing the file at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\portno_forms\default.aspx *does *modify the look of the page.

Because we are using the _login page to let the user select the authentication type, my understanding is that must remain the "default login page" and therefore I can't use that parameter to point to a custom page.

Most answers around this topic suggest changing that parameter through the Web App UI or web.config, but I don't think it applies in this case as I need multiple custom login pages, not just one.

Editing two files on the file system to do this doesn't seem like the best approach, but I have been unable to determine another method thus far.  Can you help?

Comment: What page do you want to customize in the end? The first one that prompts users to select an authentication mode, or the second one for Forms Authentication?

Comment: Both.  That is the crux of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend editing the built in login pages in place.  Instead, create a custom login page in another location (which can be just copies of the built in login pages), and point to that custom login page in your web application settings.

As for multiple types of logins, you can either put all of the different login types on a single login page, or have multiple login pages with one "login type choice" page that links to the actual login pages (you would set your web application to direct the user to the login type choice page).

A common scenario I run into is having the ability to login with either forms based authentication or windows authentication.  What I do in that case is take a copy of the built in forms based authentication page, and add a 'Windows Login' link that redirects the user to the built in windows login page.  That way both forms based and windows users can login from the single page (instead of having to go through the choose your authentication type drop down).

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I thought that might be the answer.  Sounds like you basically have to build a little collection of login pages or a page that supports more than one type on-page.  This is funny but I actually just posted about FBA Pack on your forums.  I'm going a little nuts over here because the "review" function and email aren't working, even though email on the farm is.  Are there any other special requirements for FBA Pack to talk to the email service I could check.

Comment: I've replied to your original post: http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2016-part-4-adding-users-to-the-membership-database/#comment-38569

Comment: Hey @ChrisCoulson can u please see my post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/sharepoint-2013-fba-and-ad-authentication-common-login-page and response.