# Sharepoint 2013 FBA and AD Authentication, Common Login Page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have implemented Form Based Authentication successfully using this [link](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/) in Sharepoint 2013 Foundation setup.

Internal users are AD users and I am keeping guest users in SQL server database.

Now, my requirement is that I want, to give users(internal/external) a common login page instead of giving options to choose from "Windows Authentication" OR "Form Authentication", Is it possible to handle it using Custom code? OR any OOTB feature exists?

Comment: You posted the question on my blog and i've answered it here:
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/#comment-38618

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADFS SSO for your requirement.

Please follow Microsoft blog for configuration.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/11/step-by-step-setting-up-ad-fs-and-enabling-single-sign-on-to-office-365/

Answer (score -1):

Please follow on of the article mentioned below to configure the page with both authentications.

[Branding Default Login Page for Form Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991205/Branding-Default-Login-Page-for-Form-Based-Authent)

[MIGRATION OF ACTIVE DIRECTORY USERS TO FORMS BASED AUTHENTICATION USERS](http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/migration-active-directory-users-forms-based-authentication-users)

[SharePoint 2010: Create unique login page with forms based authentication](https://davidlozzi.com/2011/07/15/sharepoint-2010-create-unique-login-page-with-forms-based-authentication/)

Comment: I wanted a common login page, this article tells about branding of FBA page.

Comment: In second article, It shows how to set a common login page for your webapplication.

Comment: Did you find it working for you?

Comment: No dear, it does'nt explains common login page, see at the end of page, two separate logins are there

Comment: Updated my answer with one more article URL. May be it helps you. Happy to help you BTW. :)